# Find random string from different xml <string-array>

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-fragments

I was trying to get a random string from the bunch of XML `<string-array>` resources, for which I have created a function:

```
public class RandomFunction {

    String[] catagories= {"marriage","life"};

    public String getRandom(Activity activity) {
        int index = new Random().nextInt(catagories.length);
        String cat = catagories[index];


        String[] data = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.**cat**);
        index = new Random().nextInt(data.length);
        cat = data[index];

        return cat;
    }  
}
```

What I am doing is taking `R.array.` and attaching the string **cat** afterwards but it's not working. How can I do this ?

Comment: use getResources().getIdentifier to retrieve the id of the string'array programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class RandomFunction {

    Context context;

    public RandomFunction(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String generate() {
        String[] albums = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat);
        List<String> albumList = Arrays.asList(albums);

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNo = random.nextInt(albumList.size());
        return albumList.get(randomNo);
    }
}
```

From multiple arrays:

```
public class RandomFunction {
Context context;
public RandomFunction(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
public String generate() {
    List < String > finalList = new ArrayList < > ();
    String[] album1 = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat1);
    List < String > albumList1 = Arrays.asList(albums);
    String[] album2 = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat2);
    List < String > albumList2 = Arrays.asList(albums);
    for (int i = 0; i < albumList1.size(); i++) {
        finalList.add(albumList1.get(i);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < albumList2.size(); j++) {
            finalList.add(albumList2.get(j);
            }
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNo = random.nextInt(albumList.size());
            return finalList.get(randomNo);
        }
    }
```

**Note the cat array should be in your values folder::: string.xml**

Comment: i dont want to extract data from a single array . i want to choose data from multiple array present in my string.xml folder..

Comment: don't understand do you mean multiple string-array objects, and randomly select from all?